# The colormap become bleak when I re-defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, visualization, colorbar

Here is my question.

The `contourf` plot showing below represent the vertical velocity of atmospheric transport in the place of interests.

[image]

What I want to do is to **set the velocity nearby 0.0 corresponding to the color white**.

So, I have tried the code below to achieve that.

```
num_levels = 20
vmin, vmax = data.min(), data.max() ## data is the 2-d array I want to show
midpoint = 0
levels = np.linspace(-1, +1, num_levels)
midp = np.mean(np.c_[levels[:-1], levels[1:]], axis=1)
vals = np.interp(midp, [vmin, midpoint, vmax], [0, 0.5, 1])
colors = plt.cm.RdBu_r(vals)
cmap, norm = from_levels_and_colors(levels, colors)
cs = plt.contourf(x,y,data,cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='none')
```

The result shows like this:

[image]

**Velocity == 0** became the midpoint of the colorbar as I would like to. But the color range of the second plot seems to be shrink. Then, the information on the second plot became unclear. **How to shift the midpoint of the colorbar without changing the color range?**

Any advice would be appreciate!

Comment: Won't setting `contourf(..., vmin=-0.3, vmax=0.4)` fix this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By setting (..., vmin = -0.3, vmax = 0.4), zero value still can't appear in the middle of colormap.